# npm install error! UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I just have intalled node for first time in my work computer with the .msi file downloaded from the official node page, clone a repo and execute

```
npm install
```

but give me the following error
[image: npm error screenshot]

I tried

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

In this other question said that you can copy and paste the cafile cert, but it doesn't work neither.
I don't know if is my version of node 12.22.12 and npm v6.14.16
others parthers in my work doesn't have this cafile set up, their value is null, so I don't know what is happening.

Comment: Contact your company's IT department ?

Comment: can you post list nvm list result?